# Different output in mouse suppression pynput.mouse

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouse, pynput

I am trying to lock the mouse pointer but still receive mouse movements. I almost achieved this goal by adding `suppress=True` in the `pynput.mouse.Listener` Here:

```
def on_move(x, y):
    print(x, y)


with pynput.mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The problem is I get an output like this when I start moving the mouse: (x on left, y on right)

```
681 551
681 550
681 550
682 550
681 551
681 550
682 550
682 551
```

But want to receive the movement of the mouse like this:

```
1 0 (mouse moved one pixel right)
0 -1 (mouse moved one pixel up)
-1 1 (mouse moved one left and one pixel down)
1 1 (mouse moved one right and one pixel down)
...
```

When moving the mouse continuously right the output is this:

```
524 364
525 364
524 364
525 364
524 364
525 364
524 364
525 364
```

Which means using the previous x as a variable like this `x - prev_x` will not be affective and will print this:

```
1 0
-1 0
1 0
-1 0
1 0
-1 0
```

Not this: (The output I would like)

```
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the edited question and seeing that your issue is that you are suppressing mouse movement, the output is logical.

```
1 0    > you are moving the mouse 1 pixel to the right
-1 0   > because the mouse is supressed it is moved back 1 pixel to it's original position
```

This output is entirely expected, when you supress the mouse.

I don't think there is a good way of supressing the mouse, that will allow for your desired output.

If you **really** need the user mouse input and **absolutely don't** want the mouse to actually move on screen, but to have it do something in your program, you might want to look for a different library to use.

Comment: "you might want to look for a different library to use." Do you have an idea of a library that will work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the program is doing as you want it to already,

but instead of stating the mouse position as a relative position (something like: "1, -1"), it is being output as an absolute position (something like: "681, 550").

In the case, that this is really your issue, the fix is simple:

```
lastx = 0
lasty = 0

def on_move(x, y):
    global lastx, lasty
    print(x - lastx, y - lasty)
    lastx = x
    lasty = y
```

that way `on_move()` will print how much your mouse moved since the last call of the function.

The vertical movement will however be "inverted", meaning a change in the y-value of -1 is not moving 1 pixel down, but 1 pixel up.

To make the y decrease instead of increasing when moving down this should work:

```
lastx = 0
lasty = 0

def on_move(x, y):
    global lastx, lasty
    print(x - lastx, lasty - y)
    lastx = x
    lasty = y
```

Note that lasty and y are swapped here, resulting in the printed vertical movement being (-1) times whatever it would be otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I actually tried this. The problem with this is that the x and y do not reset everytime. This means that `x - lastx` wont be the correct movement of the mouse. I cant seem to explain this but you can try to run your code and see for yourself

Comment: The code should work just fine, but the problem you might have is, that (-1, -1) is not 1 pixel down and one pixel left as it would be in most coordinate systems. If you want it to work like a normal coordinate system ( as you might use for mathematical purposes) you'll have to `print(x - lastx, lasty - y)`. Note that for the vertical movement (y) lasty and y are swapped.

Comment: I understand but look at my edit of the question. I added an explanation why this code code will not work. It is correlated to the way the Listener prints the position when suppressed.